# Installing Maven on Windows 11 does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, windows-11

I can't use maven on windows 11

[image: I can't use maven on windows 11]

System Variables

[image: System Variables]

PATH

[image]

java commands work perfectly
[image]

Comment: can you show the result of `echo $JAVA_HOME`? Have you restarted the cmd after set the variables?

Comment: Try in "CMD" or Git bash instead of "Power Shell"

Comment: @Tristan Why it should work properbly in the windows cmd?

Comment: Please add all the outputs as text not as images

Comment: Why what .....?

Comment: @Tristan Why should OP change from PS? It should work there in the same way

Comment: That looks odd. JAVA_HOME points to v16, while running `java` on the command line shows v19.

Comment: To see if he gets alternative results. Do u think "echo $JAVA_HOME" works in CMD ?

Comment: use `echo $env:JAVA_HOME` in powershell or `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in CMD and see if that matches your settings. I suspect the variable points to an invalid path, does that folder exist? Also whenever you change these variables, you need a new cmd/powershell instance, otherwise you won't see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happened because of the java version, it updated to version 19 and I didn't update the system variables